# Sencha touch:tabpanel design issue

Tags: cordova, extjs, sass

I have to create a tabpanel.but i'm not able to understand how to put background images for the tabs

i dont want to use iconCls.
every item or tab on the tab bar must show a different image

also i need to change the image while the tab is active and inactive
i'm unable to understand the logic behind it

i tried the following sass

```
    .x-tab{ background-image:url("../images/ftab_retailer_up.png");  height:49px;width:80px;}
```

but this sets the same image on every tab
how should i customize it for different tabs
also tried using cls

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom image like below, create a image in your .html file

```
.tabimage {
-webkit-mask-box-image: url('/public/images/image.png');
}
```

and refer it in your tabPanel using

```
iconCls: 'tabimage ',
```

for this you no need to generate the sass.

if you want to change the image of tabbar while active you can change it in touch-charts-full.css.

Comment: by using iconcls a small box is shown i want that the entire tab should show the entire image

Comment: check out the link .i have posted the image of the desired tab panelhttp://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188310-Problem-with-TabPanel-Design

Comment: try with layout: {
   pack: 'center'
  } in your tab panel

Comment: and what about the images.how to get that look??

Comment: please help. i'm stuck with it for the past 2 days

Comment: also tried icon:""with the tabbar item        {
                            xtype:'Receipts',      
                            badgeText: '4',
                            icon:"images/ftab_receipts_up.png",
                            iconMask:true
                           
                        },

Comment: i have posted  answer in your sencha forum just check with it and inform me is it working or not?.